# Calculating the sum of $f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} {n \cdot 2^n \cdot x^n}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series

In Calculus, how do I calculate this sum?

$$f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} {n \cdot 2^n \cdot x^n}$$

This is what I did so far:
$$ f(x) = 2x \cdot \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} {n \cdot 2^n \cdot x^{n-1}} $$

Therefore:
$$ \frac{\int{f(x)}}{2x} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} {2^n \cdot x^n}$$

But I have no idea where to continue from here!

Comment: Write the terms of the sum as  $n(2x)^n$ and see [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30732/how-can-i-evaluate-sum-n-0-infty-n1xn) similar question for ideas.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't even notice that haha!

Comment: The part after therefore is wrong. If you integrate, you cannot pull $x$ from the RHS in front of the integral. If you first divide and then integrate, the LHS is $\int \frac{f(x)}{x}$... The basic idea is right, but you don't need and shouldn't bring $x$ in front of the sum, just integrate in the first term.

Comment: @N.S. you are correct, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty nt^n=t\frac{d}{dt}\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty t^n\right)=t\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{t}{1-t}\right)=\frac{t}{(1-t)^2}$$

Now with $t=2x$ we find
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty n(2x)^n=\frac{2x}{(1-2x)^2}$$

Comment: Looks good to me!

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can sum the series at the point you left off,
$$
\frac{\int f(x) dx}{x} = 1 + 2x + (2x)^2 + (2x)^3 + ... = \frac{1}{1-2x}
$$
So, we work back to $f$ by itself,
$$
\int f(x) dx = \frac{x}{1-2x}
$$
We take derivatives,
$$
f(x) = \frac{(1-2x) - x (-2)}{(1-2x)^2} = \frac{1}{(1-2x)^2}
$$

Comment: Note that you start at a wrong spot, since the OP made a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a more elementary proof, which doesn't use the differentiability/integrability property of power series:

Let

$$S_m= \sum_{n=0}^{m} {n \cdot 2^n \cdot x^n}$$

Then

$$2x S_m =\sum_{n=0}^{m} {n \cdot 2^{n+1} \cdot x^{n+1}}=\sum_{k=1}^{m+1} {(k-1) \cdot 2^{k} \cdot x^{k}}$$
$$=\left(\sum_{k=1}^{m+1} k \cdot 2^{k} \cdot x^{k}\right)-\left(\sum_{k=1}^{m+1}   2^{k} \cdot x^{k}\right)=\left(\sum_{k=0}^{m+1} k \cdot 2^{k} \cdot x^{k}\right)-\left(2x\cdot\frac{1-(2x)^{m+1}}{1-2x}\right)$$
$$2xS_m=\left(S_m+(m+1)2^{m+1}x^{m+1}\right)-\left(2x\cdot\frac{1-(2x)^{m+1}}{1-2x}\right)$$

Solving for $S_m$ yields:

$$S_m=\left(2x\cdot\frac{1-(2x)^{m+1}}{(1-2x)^2}\right)-\frac{(m+1)(2x)^{m+1}}{1-2x}$$

now, $S_m$ is convergent if and only if $(2x)^{m+1} \to 0$ if and only if $|2x|<1$.

In this case

$$\lim S_m= 2x\cdot\frac{1}{(1-2x)^2}$$